# Propel and binary strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, propel

I want to differ between characters `c` and `č` or `e` and `é`.

Is it possible to handle **binary strings** for mysql with Propel? Or can I handle it without Propel directly in my MySQL-database (only for one table, some other tables still shall treat it all the same). However, queries will still be executed with Propel (does Propel support `BINARY` in queries?).

*Propel* `VARBINARY` only maps to *MySQL* `BLOB` (which is the same as *Propel* `BLOB`) and *Propel's* `VARBINARY` and `BLOB` seem pretty complicated to use (they return a resource id).

So I tried *Propel* `CLOB`, which maps to *MySQL* `LONGTEXT`. This works well in usage, but then again `e` and `é` are the same. So it is not different from my current `VARCHAR`.

Currently I am using VARCHAR with a length of 50.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html

Comment: heh... I can make it an answer if you want. It's probably a dupe of something as well I'm sure

Comment: Feel free to post an answer, I already tried to collect what I was able to see so far. Hope it is not total nonsense ;)

Comment: That looks better than what I was going to write. Mark it right ;) (except I think you might be a little confused about binary. Try not to store binary objects in your DB if you can avoid it. utf8 should be fine, I'm not sure what utf8_bin is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General about collation**

Using MySQL collation, you can specify how different characters stored in the column should be compared. To get a better overview on how each collation treats characters, you can look on [collation-charts.org](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/).

The binary collations will treat each characters differently, so characters like `e` and `é` are not the same.

To understand better how collations work, you could also have a look on the [Turkish UTF-8 collation of MySQL](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_turkish_ci.html). There you will see that `ğ` and `g` which are separate characters in Turkish are treated as different ones, whereas others are deemed the same.

Collations do not only specify which characters are the same, but also in which order they are sorted when you sort after a column.

Your choice in this case will be `utf8_bin`.

**Usage of collations in Propel**

To set the whole stuff in Propel you can use a `<vendor>` tag within your schema.xml:

```
<column name="tag" phpName="Tag" type="VARCHAR" size="50" required="true">
  <vendor type="mysql">
    <parameter name="Collate" value="utf8_bin"/>
  </vendor>
</column>
```